# Android NDK requiring absolute include paths in source files

Tags: c++, android-ndk, include

I've been working on some C++ code that compiled on Visual Studio and with MinGW/GCC just fine.

I've been using relative include paths in all of my source files.

```
#include "../../../stuff.h"
```

However a huge problem occurs when I compile on Android NDK.

If a header file has a relative include to another header file, it seems like NDK includes it relative to the original file.

So if in `"a/b/c/source.cpp"`

I do `#include "../../header.h"`

and inside of `"a/header.h"` I do

```
#include "../hello.h"
```

Instead of including from `"hello.h"` I think it goes relative to the `source.cpp` file path.  It would end up looking for it in `"a/b/header.h"`

This is fixable by me rewriting all includes within the header files to be absolute paths, which is a huge pain.  I'm hoping there's a way to avoid this with NDK.  I'm not really even sure what the problem really is, it could be some common make file command or variable that I need to set.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=" YOUR FILES DIRECTORY"
```

into your android.mk